# "Cook at 200 degrees" or "cook in 200 degrees" or something else?

Tags: word-choice

When talking about cooking in an oven, should I say "Cook at 200 degrees" or "cook in 200 degrees" or "cook on 200 degrees" or something else?

Comment: You should - cook at 200 degrees.

Comment: And if it is in degrees Celsius your food would be **baked at** 200 degrees :-)

Comment: Yes, bake at 200 degrees.  Another formulation using *in* is:  Bake *in* a 200 degree oven for 2 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When referring to temperature for an oven, you use **at**.

For example, when making [baked potatoes](http://whatscookingamerica.net/Q-A/PotatoBaking.htm)

> ...at 400 degrees F
>
> ...at too high a temperature

And usually you will "bake" or "roast" in an oven rather than "cook", though that's not a hard rule.

> Bake those potatoes at 400 degrees Fahrenheit for 45 minutes

Comment: Bake and roast are specific types of cooking, which is the more general term, so *cook* is a correct though unusual choice. (In my experience, cooking in an oven without rotisserie is only sometimes called roasting as opposed to baking, and that mostly when what is cooked is meat.) Another important preposition for relating a verb of cooking to a temperature is "to," as in "cook to an internal temperature of 135° F," which may well be done in an oven that has been preheated *to* and thus is *at* 350° F, provided one employs a good food thermometer.

Comment: If you cook fish in an oven, would you use "bake"? Or what?

Comment: If you are putting it in the oven, then yes, "bake" would be the usual term. http://www.food.com/recipe/simple-baked-fish-136746